# how to select Custom prerequisites(exe file) while Publishing a C# winform ClickOnce Application?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, clickonce

We are developing C# Winforms applications.Now i want to deploy my application using clickonce.Here i successfully added the dll reference and prerequisites(.net 4).But we are using DSO Framer control for displaying word document through our c# application.For, that we have installed an dsoframer control using dsoframer control setup exe file.

1. i want to include this Custom prerequisites with .net 4.
2. I also want to inlcude my data files...

Please guide me to get out of this issue...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ClickOnce Security and Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#ThridParty)

> You must have the redistributable package (.exe or .msi file) and describe the package with a language-neutral product manifest and a language-specific package manifest.

In order to do so you will need to [Create a Bootstrapper Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  Once you have completed that and copied the files to the correct location "the bootstrapper package automatically appears in the Visual Studio prerequisites dialog box."